# Teamleader api Key email must be present

Tags: php, api

Делаю запрос POST на teamleader API, в котором надо указать имя пользователя и его емаил, но каждый раз пишет это:

```
string(442) "{"errors":[{"code":0,"title":"Each item in emails must be valid","status":400,"meta":{"field":"emails"}},{"code":0,"title":"Key type must be present","status":400,"meta":{"field":"type"}},{"code":0,"title":"Key email must be present","status":400,"meta":{"field":"email"}},{"code":0,"title":"Key type must be present","status":400,"meta":{"field":"type"}},{"code":0,"title":"Key email must be present","status":400,"meta":{"field":"email"}}]}"
```

Ввожу разные емайлы, ничего не работает. Запрос:
`

```
$postdata = array("last_name" => "Stas ", "emails" => array("type" => "primary", "email" => $state));   
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.teamleader.eu/contacts.add");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
                ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postdata));
```

https://developer.teamleader.eu/#/reference/crm/contacts/contacts.add - вот апи, делаю как тут и ничего
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emails` должен быть массивом объектов, а у вас сразу идет объект

ваш код

```
'emails' => array(
    'type' => 'primary', 
    'email' => $state
);
```

должно быть

```
'emails' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'primary', 
        'email' => $state
    )
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает, долго не мог понять в чем дело